# Finding available mail storage, free space etc using javax.mail (or similar)

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

What can be done to know users' mail storage size, how much free space is available and how much total space is available, using javax.mail or any related library of Java?

I get the information about messages by using javax.mail api.

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
folder1 = store.getDefaultFolder();
folder1 = folder1.getFolder(boxType);
System.out.println("folder found :" 
                  + folder1.exists() 
                  + "folder name is " 
                  + folder1.getFullName());
folder1.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
messages = folder1.getMessages();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use store which implements [QuotaAwareStore](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/QuotaAwareStore.html) interface, such as [IMAPSSLStore](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPSSLStore.html) or [IMAPStore](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPStore.html). Call "getQuota" on such store and on each [Quota](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Quota.html) object check array of "resources". Each [Quota.Resource](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Quota.Resource.html) contains "limit" and "usage" values.

```
    Properties prop = System.getProperties();

    String host = "imap.gmail.com";
    String username = "user@google.com";
    String password = "some-password";

    prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    prop.setProperty("mail.imap.host", host);
    prop.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");
    prop.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
    prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    prop.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

    Session ses = Session.getInstance(prop, null);
    Store store = ses.getStore("imap");
    store.connect(host, username, password);

    if (!IMAPStore.class.isInstance(store))
        throw new IllegalStateException("Is not IMAPStore");

    IMAPStore imapStore = (IMAPStore) store;
    Quota[] quotas = imapStore.getQuota("INBOX");

    for (Quota quota : quotas) {
        System.out.println(String.format("quotaRoot:'%s'", quota.quotaRoot));

        for (Quota.Resource resource : quota.resources) {
            System.out.println(String.format("name:'%s', limit:'%s', usage:'%s'",
                    resource.name, resource.limit, resource.usage));
        }
    }
```

Output in console for my account:

```
quotaRoot:''
name:'STORAGE', limit:'10486380', usage:'1564'
```

---

**EDIT**
And another example in attempt to find correlation between quota and folder size:
[IMAP quota and folder size big example](http://pastebin.com/HSJnPQUY)

Summary, based on JavaMail JavaDoc and results from big example on GMail:

- Several `Folder`'s could have same `Quota` object. GMail, for example, have only one `Quota` shared between all folders.
- `Folder` is logical entity (not like folder on file system). For example, GMail have folder `[Gmail]/All Mail` which contains messages from other folders.
- `limit` and `usage` values returned for `Quota` by GMail measured in kilobytes.

So if you need to show how much space left you should use `Quota`. And if you need to display grid with messages and sorting by size you should use `folder.getMessages()` and `message.getSize()`.

Comment: can you give any example how to use the QuoteAwareStore, IMAPSSLStore and IMAPStore  to get mail usage

Comment: Here is example. Tested on Gmail account.

Comment: Hi  it helped me a lot. I am having one doubt is usage size consists of all the folders of account mails, the account may consists of custom folder like "abc" , "Boxbe Waiting List" and spam..etc, i want to know how many folders are available which contains mails and their respective size's.

Comment: Added another example and summary.

Comment: By using above example am getting limit is correct where as for usage am not getting the correct size.  for eg: i should get this  23.4 of 1024MB used. instead of this am getting 4 of 1024MB

Comment: Value of `Quote.Resource.usage` provided by API, so it's more reliable than aggregated sum of message sizes by folder. Most likely some message was counted more than once (thanks to `All Mail` folder or something similar). And `usage` measured in kilobytes on GMail, but my programs prints aggregated sum by folder in bytes.

Comment: Hi for second example am getting folder size, but it's taking lot of time to compile and execute. Is there any alternate way to get the folder size fast. By using   Quote.Resource.usage it taking the root as INBOX-"user"  where as my mail consists of "my", "spam","trash"

Comment: `POP3Folder` have `getSize` method which returns folder size. But `IMAPFolder` doesn't have such method, so I think you have only options from answer above - use `Quota` or retrieve size for each message in folder (it's slow, but I think you could cache size for messages (and first run will be slow anyway)).